# Remover lista de Produtos de uma Campanha - Firebase + Android Studio

Tags: java, android, lista, firebase

Tenho o bloco abaixo que adiciona uma lista de Produtos a uma Campanha

```
 recyclerProdutos.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(
                    this,
                    recyclerProdutos,
                    new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLongItemClick(View view, final int position) {
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(CampanhaActivity.this).
                                    setTitle("Adicionar Produto").
                                    setMessage("Deseja adicionar esse produto?").
                                    setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                            Produto produtoSelecionado = produtos.get(position);

                                            ProdutosCampanha produtoCampanha = new ProdutosCampanha();
                                            produtoCampanha.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                                            produtoCampanha.setUidProduto(produtoSelecionado.getUid());
                                            produtoCampanha.setNomeProCampanha(produtoSelecionado.getNome());
                                            produtoCampanha.setDescProdCampanha(produtoSelecionado.getDescricao());


                                            if (campanhaRecuperada == null) {
                                                campanhaRecuperada = new Campanha(idInstituicao);
                                                produtoCampanha.setUidCampanha(campanhaRecuperada.getUid());

                                            }

                                            produtosCampanha.add(produtoCampanha);
                                            campanhaRecuperada.setItens(produtosCampanha);
                                            produtoCampanha.setUidCampanha(campanhaRecuperada.getUid());

                                            adapterProdutosCampanha = new AdapterProdutosCampanha(produtosCampanha,CampanhaActivity.this);
                                            recyclerProdutosCampanhaAdd.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(CampanhaActivity.this));
                                            recyclerProdutosCampanhaAdd.setHasFixedSize(true);
                                            recyclerProdutosCampanhaAdd.setAdapter(adapterProdutosCampanha);

                                        }
                                    }).
                                    setNegativeButton("Não", null).show();


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        }
                    }
            )
    );
```

Ao adicionar os produtos à campanha desta forma, no Firebase o objeto é salvo desta forma
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
como a imagem anexa.

Para remover tenho o método abaixo, na qual a remoção é realizada, porém existe um problema:

```
  private void removeProdutoCampanha(final int position) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Remover Produto")
            .setMessage("Deseja remover esse Produto da Campanha?")
            .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    ProdutosCampanha produto = new ProdutosCampanha();
                    ProdutosCampanha produtosCampanhaAdd = produtosCampanha.get(position);
                    produtosCampanha.remove(produto);
                    removeProduto(position,uidProCamp);
                    produtosCampanha.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Não",null).show();
}

private void removeProduto(,int position,String uidProCamp) {

    produtoCampanhaRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("Campanha").child(idCampanha).child("itens").child(String.valueOf(position));
    produtoCampanhaRef.removeValue();


}
```

Exemplo: Caso eu exclua o item com posição 01 da lista, no Firebase este item 01 é excluído ficando item 0 ,2 ,3 ,4

conforme a imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja se na próxima vez eu passar a posição 02, não vai existir e não vou conseguir excluir.

não estou conseguindo acessar um item especifico para fazer a exclusão.

Remover lista de Itens dentro de uma Campanha - Firebase + Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira mais simples que vi de fazer essa exclusão sem fazer grandes alterações no teu código é a seguinte:

Já que no momento que tu chama o método de exclusão tu tens acesso à lista de produtos então o que tu deves fazer é remover desta lista o item que tu queres excluir e depois salvar a lista novamente no firebase. Dessa forma ele vai sobrescrever o nó itens e os produtos em cada indice serão ajustados.

1.Obtenha o indice que deve ser excluido;
2. remova da lista de produtos o item que estiver no indice;
3.dentro do teu metodo removeProduto salve a lista de produtos novamente no nó "itens"

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso. No método removeProduto, removi o produto na posição. Como o método salvarCampanha esta em outra classe foi necessário fazer um for no adapter, para retornar os itens atualizados do adapter e adicionei esse itens em uma nova lista e salvei essa nova lista.  Não se é a melhor forma de fazer, ter esse for no adapter, mas da maneira como estruturei o código foi a saída que encontrei. Muito obrigado

Comment: Não é a melhor forma de fazer mas é a que mais aproveita o teu código.Para melhorar sugiro que leia o artigo no link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=pt-br#read_data_once

Comment: Lerei . Obrigado pela ajuda